# Does the pgfplots manual crash your Preview and/or Skim app on OSX?

Tags: pgfplots, documentation, mac, viewers

The `pgfplots` manual consistently crashes both my Preview.app and my Skim.app. A quick google search yields a [closed bug report on the `pgfplots` Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3485226&group_id=192583&atid=941981) and a [related question on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55578/preview-chrashes-on-certain-page-of-pgfplots-manual), showing that this is a known issue. It doesn't happen on every page; it seems to prefer pages with more elaborate plots. Though this is not technically a TeX question it will only affect TeX users; according to the closed bug report it is Apple's bug and there's not much that can be done about it, I wanted to check if anyone else has encountered this problem and figured out a way—any way—*around it* for long enough to work through one of the examples in the manual (or am I doomed to screen-capturing it?!).

---

## Edit

As per Christian Feuersänger's suggestion, here are some Minimal Crashing Examples. On another note Adobe Reader (version 9) works with all of these plots, though compared to Skim or Preview, it is slow and choppy; you can almost feel it strain to get the job done.

### Parametrized plot crash

```
% pgfplots manual, page 121
% parametrized plot #4
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% This one crashes unceremoniously. 

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,
    samples=30,domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi]
    ({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
    {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
    x);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

### Patch Plot, biquadratic

```
% pgfplots manual, page 343
% patch type, biquadratic
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% This one renders the axes and then hangs before plotting.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={Mesh on top of patches (i): obscured}]

\addplot3[patch,patch type=biquadratic,shader=interp,
  patch refines=3]
coordinates {
 (0,0,1) (6,1,1.6) (5,5,1.3) (-1,5,0)
 (3,1,0) (6,3,0.4) (2,6,1.1) (0,3,0.9)
 (3,3.75,0.5)
};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=biquadratic,mesh,black,
  patch refines=3]
coordinates {
  (0,0,1) (6,1,1.6) (5,5,1.3) (-1,5,0)
  (3,1,0) (6,3,0.4) (2,6,1.1) (0,3,0.9)
  (3,3.75,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

### Patch plot, bilinear

```
% pgfplots manual, page 343
% patch type, biliniear
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% Not the same as the bilinear example on the pgfplots manual because that one
% reads data from a file I don't have. 
% This one renders the axes and then hangs before plotting.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={Mesh on top of patches (i): obscured}]

\addplot3[patch,patch type=bilinear,shader=interp,
  patch refines=3]
coordinates {
 (0,0,1) (6,1,1.6) (5,5,1.3) (-1,5,0)
 (3,1,0) (6,3,0.4) (2,6,1.1) (0,3,0.9)
 (3,3.75,0.5)
};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=biquadratic,mesh,black,
  patch refines=3]
coordinates {
  (0,0,1) (6,1,1.6) (5,5,1.3) (-1,5,0)
  (3,1,0) (6,3,0.4) (2,6,1.1) (0,3,0.9)
  (3,3.75,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

### Patch plot, bicubic

```
% pgfplots manual, page 336
% patch type, bicubic
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% This one renders differently than in the manual. Uglier.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[nodes near coords={(\coordindex)},
  title=Single Bicubic Quadrilateral]
\addplot3[patch,patch type=bicubic,shader=interp]
coordinates {
  (0,0,1) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
  (0,1,0) (1,1,0) (2,1,0) (3,1,0)
  (0,2,0) (1,2,0) (2,2,0) (3,2,0)
  (0,3,0) (1,3,0) (2,3,0) (3,3,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%% Switched to pdflatex engine because of this error: 
% ERROR: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, surface shading (shader=interp) is NOT
% available for the selected driver `pgfsys-xetex.def'. I will use 'shader=flat'
% if you continue now.

%% Output is not as expected or as shown in the manual

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

### Patch plot, bicubic (a crashing one)

```
% pgfplots manual, page 337
% patch type, bicubic
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% This one renders axes and then hangs.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=Two Bicubic Patches]
\addplot3[patch,patch type=bicubic,shader=interp,point
    meta=explicit]
coordinates {
    (0,0,1)[1] (1,0,0)[0] (2,0,0)[0] (3,0,0)[0]
    (0,1,0)[0] (1,1,0)[0] (2,1,0)[0] (3,1,0)[0]
    (0,2,0)[0] (1,2,0)[0] (2,2,0)[0] (3,2,0)[0]
    (0,3,0)[0] (1,3,0)[0] (2,3,0)[0] (3,3,0)[0]
    (3,0,0)[0] (4,0,0)[0] (5,0,0)[0] (6,0,0)[0.7]
    (3,1,0)[0] (4,1,.5)[1](5,1,0)[0] (6,1,0)[0]
    (3,2,0)[0] (4,2,0)[0] (5,2,0)[0] (6,2,0)[0]
    (3,3,0)[0] (4,3,0)[0] (5,3,0)[0] (6,3,0)[0.1]
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%% Switched to pdflatex engine because of this error: 
% ERROR: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, surface shading (shader=interp) is NOT
% available for the selected driver `pgfsys-xetex.def'. I will use 'shader=flat'
% if you continue now.


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

### Patch plot, coons

```
% pgfplots manual, page 337-338
% patch type, coons
% Compiled: 2012-11-02
% This one renders differently than in the manual

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[nodes near coords={(\coordindex)},
  width=12cm,
  title=A Coons Patch]
\addplot[mark=*,patch,patch type=coons,
  shader=interp,point meta=explicit]
coordinates {
  (0,0) [0] % first corner
  (1,-1) [0] % Bezier control point between (0) and (3)
  (4,0.7) [0] % Bezier control point between (0) and (3)
%
  (3,2) [1] % second corner
  (4,3.5) [1] % Bezier control point between (3) and (6)
  (7,2) [1] % Bezier control point between (3) and (6)
%
  (7,1) [2] % third corner
  (6,0.6) [2] % Bezier control point between (6) and (9)
  (4.5,-0.5) [2] % Bezier control point between (6) and (9)
%
  (5,-2) [3] % fourth corner
  (4,-2.5) [3] % Bezier control point between (9) and (0)
  (-1,-2) [3] % Bezier control point between (9) and (0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

%% Switched to pdflatex engine because of this error: 
% ERROR: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, surface shading (shader=interp) is NOT
% available for the selected driver `pgfsys-xetex.def'. I will use 'shader=flat'
% if you continue now.


%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Comment: A while ago, the previewer with TeXworks used to hang on me -- only occurred if the image occupied the full width of the page as per the current zoom. Hasn't happened since I updated to a newer TeXworks, but then I haven't worked much with figures in a while.  But, have never has a problem with manual -- and I pretty much always use Preview to view them, but I am on 10.6.8.

Comment: I have the exact same OS and Preview version as the one reported in linked question at apple.SE and I have never had it crash with the `pgfplots` manual. Perhaps, you could try Acrobat.

Comment: Before today, it had never crashed before; not with the `pgfplots`manual nor with any other large document. At first I thought it was an issue with Preview, but then it also crashed Skim. Both times I was either zooming in or moving around the document using gestures. I think I have Acrobat somewhere in this machine. I will (reluctantly) give it a try and report back. In the mean time, I just crashed Skim again (just because I could!) and have the report dump at hand. Any suggestions as to what I should do with it?

Comment: Perhaps your the PDF is corrupted. Try re downloading it. Don't overwrite the existing file, create a new one.

Comment: I had the version from October 26, 2012. It seems to be the latest version. I downloaded it again, this time from the SourceForge site, and saved it to a different location. Scrolled using trackpad gestures. Soon enough, it had crashed Preview again.

Comment: Concerning the pgfplots manual, I am aware of the fact the some special shadings cause problems with open-source viewers. This affects `shader=interp` for `surf` plots and all shadings of the `patchplots` library. Apparently, free viewers use bad implementations. I have implemented the shader for `libpoppler` and the implementation has been accepted. Perhaps Skim and preview rely on some related buggy library (`pdfkit`?). Can you confirm that it happens on specific pages - like those containing smooth surface plots with shadings?

Comment: Note that in case your crash dump contains specific information about "corruption" in that manual, I would really want to see and fix it. I am unaware of any such problems, but who knows.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I looked for `surface plots` but nothing happened. Then I scrolled a bit trying to find more surface plots and managed to consistently crash it on page 344. I can also crash it straight from the table of contents by clicking or hovering over the heading that links to page 344 (`Polar axes `). Same thing with page 120 (`Parametrized plots`), though unlike page 344, page 120 gives me a crash report every time.

Comment: Here's the crash report I get on page 120 and onwards.[http://pastebin.com/iC94c6Dz]. Here's the crash report for page 344: [http://pastebin.com/iMLV9ayt], and for good measure, here's the Preview crash report: [http://pastebin.com/MPD6bsXf]. I don't know how to read them; I didn't find the word "corruption" or "pgfplots" in them, but you may know what to look for.

Comment: The pastebin urls are appending a closing bracket, making them resolve to an Unknown Paste ID. If you remove the bracket they should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, your crash dumps indicate problems with shadings: `type4_read_triangle` (generated by `surf,shader=interp`); another one has the stack trace element `MakeCoonsMesh` and `cg_shading_type6_draw` (which is used by lots of higher-order `patch type`s combined with `shader=interp`.

I cannot say if `pgfplots` has done something in a wrong way. Considering that `acroread` does not complain, and that most other free viewers also supports the shadings (although they are often inefficient and/or have bad quality), I would say that we can simply confirm that it is an error in the viewer. After all, it should not crash. Never.

Perhaps you can use acrobat reader to find a suitable example which has been generated using these shadings in order to produce a minimal crashing example. This might be very useful for the viewer guys who try to fix the bug (probably the `pdfkit` library as it seems).

Note that you should use at least two examples; better three: one with a standard `surf,shader=interp` plot and at least one with an advanced `patch type`. Perhaps one with `patch type=bilinear,shader=interp` and one with `patch type=bicubic,shader=interp`. Then you would have all three different PDF Shading types (4 + 5 which are almost the same and 6 and 7). This is probably what interests the `pdfkit` library guys. The manual should provide matching examples.

Comment: as you suggested, I found the crashing examples and turned them into MWE. I will edit the question to include them, though if there's another way I should go about this, I will be happy to oblige.

Comment: I will also mark the question as answered, because using Acrobat Reader I can look through the examples and things don't crash. Not terribly comfortable, but definitely more convenient than the alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for collecting these examples. This leaves two more things to do: (1) to add `\pdfcompresslevel=0` before `\documentclass` (such that people can easily inspect the pdf data) and (2) a bug report to the developers if the viewers in question. You can certainly link to this site, although that might be unnecessary if you give them the offending `.pdf` documents.